# DockStyle.Fill cuts off horizontal content

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-standard

**Problem:**
My `TableLayoutPanel` always has some horizontal content clipped - seems to be exactly the width of the scrollbar.

**Expected result:** I want all of the horizontal content to be shown, with no horizontal scrollbar. I want the vertical scrollbar shown.

**Setting:** I have a `Panel` with AutoScroll = True. Inside I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with Dock = DockType.Fill and AutoScroll = True. I created these in Design view, not programmatically.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And here's the designer code:

```
'
'Panel1 - This is the Panel
'
Me.Panel1.AutoScroll = True
Me.Panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = New System.Drawing.Size(0, 100)
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.pnlColumns)
Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(566, 379)
Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 4
'
'pnlColumns - this is the TableLayoutPanel
'

Me.pnlColumns.AutoScroll = True
Me.pnlColumns.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver
Me.pnlColumns.ColumnCount = 3
Me.pnlColumns.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 75.0!))
Me.pnlColumns.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 150.0!))
Me.pnlColumns.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 341.0!))
Me.pnlColumns.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
Me.pnlColumns.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
Me.pnlColumns.Name = "pnlColumns"
Me.pnlColumns.RowCount = 14
Me.pnlColumns.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 30.0!))
' other rows removed for brevity
Me.pnlColumns.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(566, 379)
Me.pnlColumns.TabIndex = 0
```

Comment: You have a TLP with fixed Columns there, so you don't want to Dock->Fill it, you probably prefer to keep the anchors and set `AutoSize = true`. Size the  `Panel.Width = TLP.Width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth + TLP.Margin.Left + TLP.Margin.Right` (or, well, just *large enough*), so when the TLP increases its vertical size, the Vertical ScrollBar won't *steal* any space and the Horizontal ScrollBar won't appear. Only the Panel needs `AutoScroll = true`, not the TLP.

Comment: Thanks - that solved it. On the TableLayoutPanel I removed the Dock property, added Anchor (Left, Top) and increased the width of the parent Panel.